# RubyMine Unit tests - Test Framework quit unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rvm, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

When I try to run the tests from within RubyMine I have an issue. But what is strange is that it work fine when I run the tests from the command line.

**"Test framework quit unexpectedly"**

[image]

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Itest /Users/sabour/Desktop/EIP/project/test/controllers/categories_controller_test.rb
Testing started at 1:39 AM ...
Run options: --seed 14336

# Running tests:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228: warning: nested repeat operator + and ? was replaced with '*'
...

Finished tests in 2.554592s, 1.1744 tests/s, 8.6119 assertions/s.

3 tests, 22 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Maybe the problem come from that line ?

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228: warning: nested repeat operator + and ? was replaced with '*' ...

**Mode:** Test script
**Use pre-load server:** none
**Ruby arguments:** -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Itest
**Ruby SDK:** project

But I would love to have something like this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: From what you printed, all tests went through as the process finished with exit code 0. The warning has nothing to do with it and shoulb be easy to fix.

Comment: I have added some screens. I know it's just a warning but I want to have the same view as the second screen.

Comment: Any solution for this? I have same problem.

Comment: Not sure if it was actually the fix, but I 1) closed RubyMine, 2) deleted project's .idea folder and 3) reopened project and the tests were available again

Answer (score 18):

There is a [nice tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/minitest.html) for setting up RubyMine tests in their online help, which helped me resolve the same problem as you describe (for `Test::Unit`-style tests). Basically you need to include the `minitest` and `minitest-reporters` gems into your project and add a call to use the new format of tests reporting:

```
# Gemfile
group :test do
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
end

# test/test_helper.rb
require 'minitest/reporters'
MiniTest::Reporters.use!
```

Take a look at the tutorial for more options.

Comment: thanks! All ready had the gems, just needed the magic lines in the test_helper.rb

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, and it was caused by not installing (globally?) the ruby gems of the testing library. For instance, for the **minitest** testing framework (you didn't specify which one you use), just run from command line:

```
gem install minitest
gem install minitest-reporters
```

This solved the problem to me.

Comment: This also solved my problem.  However I had to explicitly define the minitest version to be '~> 4.7.5' because it was an older project...

Comment: Solved my problem : I use the standard Test::Unit and at first it was only using the version bundled with ruby. I added the test-unit gem with

`gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0.1'` in my Gemfile

and after an update with Bundler, RubyMine began to recognize my tests.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I don't even have a Gems folder in my library folder.

Comment: Thanks!  RubyMine didn't install the minitest gems automatically because it's running on Linux; started working once I ran "sudo gem install ...".

Comment: After installing these gems I had to restart the IDE, to make everything work.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when running from RubyMine (but not from command line). It was fixed by restarting spring:

```
bin/spring stop
bin/spring status
```

Comment: This fixed for me with RubyMine 7.0.4 and Rails 4.2. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you have two tests with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it specifying the PATH for RSpec. To find the right path in Ubuntu, I used the command

> whereis rpsec

In RubyMine, go to menu "Run" > "Edit Configurations", mark "Use custom RSpec runner script", and set the path found previously.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed this by removing 'guard-minitest' from Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that your test suite is running with `RAILS_ENV=test`

For RubyMine you can set this up in `Run > Edit Configurations.. > Choose test suite you want to run (i.e. spec: project_name) > Environment variables` and there add variable mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error when some of the gems are not checked out, so you will need to run `bundle install`. Run your test from terminal and you will get an error if that is your case