# Empty test suite - Test-Unit RubyMine

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rubymine, testunit, rubymine-7

this is my first time using RubyMine and I can't make the Test Framework recognize the tests.

If I run the `greed.rb` file it shows the result of the tests:
[image]

But if I run the tests it shows this:
[image]

I have read the [question about minitest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570266/rubymine-unit-tests-test-framework-quit-unexpectedly) and tried to apply it to test-unit but it did not worked.

This is the content of my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0.8'
```

And this is part of the ruby class that contains the tests:

```
require 'test/unit'

def score(dice)
  # code of the function
end

class Greed < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_score_of_an_empty_list_is_zero
      assert_equal 0, score([])
    end
end
```

I'm probably missing something but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it I firstly restructured my project in the following way

```
/lib
  greed.rb
/tests
  test_greed.rb
Gemfile
```

Then I moved all of my tests to the new file

```
require './lib/greed.rb'
require 'test/unit'

class Test_Greed < Test::Unit::TestCase
# code for the tests
end
```

Finally I went to `File/Setting/Project/Project Structure` and marked the tests folder as `Test` (this should change the color of the folder icon).

Now I can run the tests using the testing framework
[image]